# Perform calculations on numeric text in an element

Tags: jquery, html

I have stored a value in one p tag and then i have this condition question.
If people select yes, there's nothing changed of the answer. If people select no, then i will subtract a number from the answer and display it at the same position.
How can i play around with these 2 options, if i select yes again, the number won't go back to the original answer.
How can make this work?
Thanks.

html:

```
Do you have a yard
<input type="radio" name="ownyard" value="0">Yes
<input type="radio" name="ownyard" id="yard1" value="0.09789">No
<br>Total trash weight (based on your purchasing behavior):
<p id="wastetotal" class="answer">0.707</p>&nbsp;metric tons
```

jquery:

```
$("input[name='ownyard']:radio").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var totalwaste = parseFloat($("#wastetotal").text());
    if ($("#yard1").is(":checked")) {

        var newtrash = totalwaste - value;
    } else {
        var newtrash = totalwaste + value;
    }
    $("#wastetotal").html(newtrash);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Use `parseFloat` on both values. Values simplified for clarity in this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nXYGE/

```
$("input[name='ownyard']:radio").change(function () {
    var value = parseFloat( $(this).attr('value') );
    var totalwaste = parseFloat( $("#wastetotal").text() );

    if ($("#yard1").is(":checked")) {
        var newtrash = totalwaste - value;
    } else {
        var newtrash = totalwaste + value;
    }

    $("#wastetotal").text(newtrash);
});
```

Note that I also cleaned up your HTML a bit for clarity and consistency.

Comment: Good point about `value` This doesn't show the number that hasn't been subtracted though as he originally asked

Answer (score 0):

Capturing original value something like this?

```
var originalwaste = 0.0, isOriginal = false;
$("input[name='ownyard']:radio").change(function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('value')),
        totalwaste = parseFloat($("#original").text());
    if ( !( isOriginal ) ) {
        originalwaste = totalwaste; // So now the original waste is stored, you can edit or use it in the future.
        isOriginal = true;
    }
    if ($("#yard1").is(":checked")) {
        var newtrash = totalwaste - value;
    } else {
        var newtrash = totalwaste + value;

    }
    $("#current").html(newtrash);
    $("#original").html(originalwaste);
});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/NNxpn/)

Comment: i used parseFloat :) do you know how can i display the original number before edited ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"display"_. On the screen or?